# Eclipse SVN Error : svn: E175002: Connection has been shutdown

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I was trying to commit my files from eclipse to SVN. It started failing recently.
I was able to commit using the SVNT native client without any issues.

This is the error that I am getting.

Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: E175002: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/netsuite/NetSuite/ncr'

I upgraded to latest tortoise svn, I upgraded eclipse to eclipse:mars. But still not luck.

Answer (score 3):

I had to uninstall the SVNKIT(optional package and install Native JAVAHL Packages for 64bit from the eclipse marketplace. That finally solved my issue.

Comment: it works, thx
`eclipse -> help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Installed -> Subclipse -> Change -> Install Now`